# Help with a limit of a certain differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I have an ODE $y’+a(t)y=b(t)$ with initial condition $y(0)=0$.

The functions $a(t),b(t)$ are continuous and each of them satisfy
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}a(t)=A>0.$$ And $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}b(t)=B>0.$$

When I graph $y$, I see that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}y(t)=B/A.$$.m, but I don’t know how to prove it analytically. Maybe it’s simple and I am overcomplicating. If I take the limit as $t\rightarrow \infty$, then the ODE becomes $y’+Ay=B$ and intuitively, the conclusion is clear but I’m not sure if I can do such thing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion: Solve the equation with an integrating factor first.

Comment: The solution of this ODE is pretty nasty and it’s solution even has polylogarithm of second order. I want to know if there’s a neat proof to it without solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that we're considering solutions over $[0,\infty)$. Define:
$$A(x) = \int_{0}^{x} a(t) \ dt$$
Then, $A'(x) = a(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Similarly, define:
$$B(x) = \int_{0}^{x} b(t) \ dt$$
Multiplying by $e^{A(x)}$, we find that:
$$(y(x)e^{A(x)})' = b(x) e^{A(x)}$$
$$y(x)e^{A(x)} = \int_{0}^{x} b(t) e^{A(t)} \ dt$$

It follows that for all $x \geq 0$:
$$y(x) = \frac{\int_{0}^{x} b(t)e^{A(t)} \ dt }{e^{A(x)}}$$
Now, observe that:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{b(x)e^{A(x)}}{A'(x)e^{A(x)}} = \frac{B}{A}$$

The answer is obtained by applying L'Hôpital's Rule when taking the limit of $y(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: The formula for y is basically the one used to solve first order linear ODE. But shouldn’t y(t) be the same but with interval of integration from 0 to t and integrating with respect to t?

Comment: I suspect that in the second step after multiplying by the integration factor, what appears In t should be x right?

Comment: Well, no. $t$ is the variable that you're integrating with respect to. $x$ is a fixed real number.

Comment: I think there's a typo in that all the $dx$'s should be $dt$'s.

Comment: Ahh nice, I didn't notice that, I guess that's what Brenda meant earlier?

Comment: Yes I meant that. Now it’s clear. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem at all